# How to bind a multi record HTML form data to AutoPopulatingList

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I am building a paginated form which allows traversing the entire "Book" table page by page and allows updating the entire page of records with one submission.

The screen will have a two dimensional form with rows and columns of text boxes, like a spread sheet, where each row corresponds to one Book object in the page and each column corresponds the fields of the Book object.

### Steps taken:

1.Used a PagingAndSortingRepository to retrieve Page records

2.Copied the list of books to a FormBean backed by AutoPopulatingList

I am using freemarker templates for screen(because Spring boot documentation advises to avoid JSP while developing a spring boot app)

### Help needed on:

**Q1)** How to bind the AutopopulatingList to freemarker's @Spring.bind and render one row of @spring.formInput text boxes (one text box per Book fields) (presently i rendered it using plain html and freemarker <#list> tags)

**Q2)** How to read the submitted form values into myFormBean.AutoPopulatingList

### My Form Bean

```
//Form Bean backed by AutoPopulatingList
//Use AutoPopulatingList to allow flexible page sizes
public class MyBookListFormBean {

    private AutoPopulatingList<Book>  booksList;
    //getter, setter, constructor
    public void add(List<Book> books) {
        booksList.addAll(books); //copy paged data into AutoPopulatingList 
    }
}
```

### Controller methods

```
  //show Form page method. 
  //This allows to navigate through the table 
  //and show a form screen per page of data which can be submitted to different URL. 
  //this method is run when "first/prev/next/last" links below the form are clicked
  @RequestMapping(value="/books")
  public String showPagedForm(Model model, Pageable page,
                @ModelAttribute("booksForm") MyBookListFormBean formBean ) {

    Page<Book> allBooks = booksRepository.findAll(pageable);
    model.addAttribute("booksPage",allBooks); 
    formBean.addToList(allBooks.getContent());  //add current page data to Form Bean
    return "/books/index";
  }


  //submit Form
  @RequestMapping(value="/books/updateAPageOfRecords" method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public String updateAPageOfRecords( Model model, Pageable page, 
         @ModelAttribute("booksForm") MyBookListFormBean formBean, 
         BindingResult result  )   {
    //tried to print the submitted data
    //NOTHING got bound !!!

  }
```